# How can I transform data from a nominal column to a discreet column in Scala

Tags: bigdata, data-mining

I am implementing an algorithm to obtain association rules in Big Data environments. At this moment my algorithm only works with purely numerical databases but does not work with nominal databases. I need a way to transform the data in the nominal columns to numerical values ​​so that each nominal value is associated with a discrete numerical value. So far I have only managed to obtain the different values ​​that are in each column.

```
db.schema.foreach { column =>
      val valuesDistinct = db.select(column.name).distinct
      val values = valuesDistinct.map(row => row(0).toString).collect
    }
```